# Definition of an implicit region with Resolve

Tags: regions

I am trying to define a region so I can calculate its volume with `Volume[region]`.

Here is an example of the problem I am having (my real function `f` is much more complicated).

```
function[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Resolve[Exists[i, i ∈ Integers && i > 0 && i < 3 && -i < 0 && x < i]]
ImplicitRegion[function[x, y, z] && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}]
```

It seems my region is not correctly specified. Where did I make an error in syntax of `ImplicitRegion`?

Comment: Why `TrueQ`? Of course it gives `False`; consider `TrueQ[a < 0]` - no assumptions on `a`. Moreover, why `Resolve`? Well, I guess it's an artifact of your bigger problem. Nevertheless: `region = ImplicitRegion[
  function[x, y, z] && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}]` and `Volume[region]` yields `1.52494`

Comment: I have changed the code so that it better corresponds to my real problem.

Comment: `TrueQ` is for programming, not for representing mathematical ideas.  `TrueQ[anything]` is `False`.  Only `TrueQ[True]` is `True`.  Why did you use `TrueQ` here?

Comment: Sorry, I have made some changes again.

Comment: But TrueQ of Resolve[...] should not simply give Resolve[...]?

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
Exists[i, i ∈ Integers && i > 0 && i < 3 && -i < 0 && x < i]
```

is equivalent to

```
Exists[i, i ∈ Integers && 0 < i < 3 && x < i]
```

which is clearly equivalent to

```
x < 2
```

That's the half space of all points `{x, y, z}` with `x < 2`. This half space contains the unit sphere, the other component of your region, so the volume of their intersection is the volume of the sphere. That is, 4 π/3.

Comment: The above functin f was only some example, which should only show that by such a syntax I get an error from Mathematica (ImplicitRegion ... is not a correctly specified region.), which I do not understand. How  could I avoid the error?

Comment: @Agnieszka. Your example is trivial and is not a good model for you real problem. We can't help you when you give us a trivial example. Without  your real code or something close to it, there is no way for anyone to know what corrections to might work.